# Multiple string replacement through php file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, string, str-replace

Here's what I have for my function, it gets activated by pressing a button, sending two input id's to form the a string:

```
var str = "headingText=" + $("#headingText").val() +
    "&centerText=" + $("#centerText").val();

$.ajax({
    url: "indexpdf.php",
    data: str,
    cache: false,
    success: function (result) {
        console.log("Success!");
    }
});
```

Now here's my indexpdf.php file:

```
<?
$headingText = trim(isset($_POST['headingText']) ? $_POST['headingText'] : '');
$centerText = trim(isset($_POST['centerText']) ? $_POST['centerText'] : '');

$initialpdf = file_get_contents('file_html.php');

$initialpdf = str_replace(array(
        '%headingText%',
        '%centertext%'
    ), array (
        $headingText,
        $centerText,
    ), $initialpdf);

$fp = fopen('file_html2.php','w');
file_put_contents('file_html2.php', $initialpdf);
?>
```

The goal here, is to take the two strings from the first page's inputs and use them to replace all "%headingText%" and "%centerText%" tags in "file_html.php" and then finally save it as "file_html2.php".

The file is saving fine, but the string replacement is not working..

Comment: Doing a string replacement on an executable PHP file from POST data is very dangerous. A user could run any PHP code they like on your server.  And is $initialpdf a PDF file?

Comment: Are you sure it's post and not get?

Comment: @MattS how would I be able to get what I'm doing done securely? and no, $initialpdf is just an array.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I changed to GET and it worked. although now I'm worried about Matt's comment about this being unsafe.

Comment: @NoReceipt4Panda If your file is actually HTML, name it `file.html` so your web server won't execute it as PHP.  That will make it safe for the user to edit.

Comment: Pass the data as an object instead of query string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ajax` call isn't set to any method. It will automatically use `$_GET`. If you want it to use `$_POST`, you could do the shorthand:

Pages fetched with POST are never cached, so the cache and ifModified options in jQuery.ajaxSetup() have no effect on these requests.

```
$.post("indexpdf.php", data: str,function (result) {
        console.log("Success!");
});
```

Or simply add the "method" option to your `ajax`.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "indexpdf.php",
    data: str,
    method: "POST",
    cache: false,
    success: function (result) {
        console.log("Success!");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$.ajax` by default uses GET method. If the server side code is expecting to receive POST data, then you have to add this:

```
$.ajax({
method: "POST",
...
});
```

Also, if you use `file_put_contents()` there is no need for `fopen()`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing a Query String for all to see, pass a JSON object as follows:

```
        var jsonData = {}
        jsonData.headingText = $("#headingText").val();
        jsonData.centerText = $("#centerText").val();

        $.ajax({
            url: "indexpdf.php",
            data: jsonData,
            cache: false,
            success: function (result) {
                alert("Success!");
            }
        });
```

This is cleaner and safer. Accessing the data can remain the same in the PHP file.